# What to do with the inner converter of view scoped backing bean

Tags: jsf, converters, inner-classes, view-scope

Yet another problem among others with view scoped backing beans in JSF. I created an inner class in my view scoped backing bean. That inner class is converter. I need the inner class because I have to access some fields from my backing bean (list of select-one items in this case). Suddenly I figure out that my backing bean's `@PostConstruct` method is called after every request. After some inspection I realized that converter attribute is the problem and after some google search a find on (as always) [BalusC's blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) reason for this.

So, my question is how to make my converter to work fine, and also have my list of data which is necessary for conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decouple the converter into a stand alone class and use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) to access the view scoped bean instance inside the converter method.

```
ViewBean viewBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{viewBean}", ViewBean.class);
```

This is however a bit nasty design. If I understand your concrete functional requirement of converting the selected item based on the list of available items right, an alternative is to use a generic converter which converts based on the physical `<f:selectItem>`/`<f:selectItems>` components. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has two converters for exactly this purpose, the [`SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) and [`SelectItemsIndexConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsIndexConverter).

Comment: Perfect, thank you BalusC. OmniFaces has few additional things which I'm interested in, and I think it is a moment to start using it. I just hope that it will not cause me some other side effects.

Comment: You're welcome. As of version 1.3 it should not cause any side effects as far as I see.

Comment: This is a generic problem to me. I have avoided converters because they always need access to Collections that live in my backing bean. I have used IDs instead (`value="#{mybean.objectId}) with ID getters and setters. BalusC will probably spank me for this and he should because it leads to other ugly problems, basically doing the conversion in the getters and setters. But I see no more graceful alternative.